# How javascript can get a ModelAndView object from a function in spring controller

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

I know this is a simple question, so if you find it as duplicate please note me to remove.

Here is my spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    .
    .
    .    

    @RequestMapping("/testActiveX")
    protected ModelAndView testActiveX(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("test_ActiveX");
        model.addObject("APDU","00A4040008A000000018434D00");
        return model;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Here is my jsp page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function func(apdu) {
                alert(apdu);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>                
        <button type="button" style= "height: 30px; width: 153px" onclick="func(${APDU});">click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why I can not access to `APDU` value in my javascript function?

Comment: Expand on what is happening. What does the page source show? onclick="func(00A4040008A000000018434D00); or something else?

Comment: you need to make ajax call to access the value

Comment: It shows this message: Expected ')' and a link that explain something like this: You attempted to enclose an expression within a set of parentheses, but did not include the closing parenthesis. Some expression must be enclosed within a set of opening and closing parentheses. Notice the use of parentheses in the following example.

Comment: The call function error occurred exactly here: `onclick="func(00` , exactly after two zeroes.

Comment: page source shows: `onclick="func(00A4040008A000000018434D00);"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your comments, adding commas should resolve your issue

```
onclick="func('${APDU}');"
```

Comment: how can we get a jsp variable (i.e. a textarea input) in a class (i.e. spring controller) with a function which return a ModelAndView object?